# how to differentiate user typed their own value or selected a suggestion from typeahead

Tags: typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using typeahead.js.

```
var getname = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('CompanyName'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: '/Profile/Getname?searchText=%QUERY',
});
getname.initialize();
var $emp = $('#employment');
$emp.typeahead(null, {
    name: 'CompanyNames',
    displayKey: 'CompanyName',
    source: getname.ttAdapter(),

});
$emp.on("typeahead:selected", function (obj, user) {

    $("#UserId").val(user.UserID);
  }
```

is there a way to know when the user selects an option from the list or typed their own value?

Answer (score 0):

I made it that way

```
var voivodeshipSelected = false;
$('input[name=voivodeshipSelect].typeahead').on('typeahead:select', function (ev, suggestion) {
    $(this).validationEngine('hide');
    voivodeshipSelected = true;
});

$('input[name=voivodeshipSelect].typeahead').on('typeahead:change', function (ev, data) {
    if (!voivodeshipSelected) {
        $(this).validationEngine('showPrompt', 'choose voivodeship', 'error', 'topRight', true);
    }
    else {
        voivodeshipSelected = false;
    }
});
```

I just add global variable which is set on select so than on change which is binded when select, check it, and showing prompt or not.